Xray Core does not respond to domain search
Im currently trying to setup Xray-core and 3x-ui to make residential proxies as explained in this SO question. Im on macOS but I downloaded UTM and created a Linux VM. I downloaded both Xray and 3x-ui and made sure they're both running correctly with no errors. When I setup 3x-ui I chose Cloudflare SSL Certificate and setup a domain as seen in the image below (I also set up DNS record) to resolve to the public IP that Xray/3x-ui are running on.
The problem is that I can only access the 3x-ui panel from the localhost http://localhost:12345 and hackproxies:12345 shows a Host error.



Config.json
{
 "api": {
   "services": [
     "HandlerService",
     "LoggerService",
     "StatsService"
   ],
   "tag": "api"
 },
 "burstObservatory": null,
 "dns": null,
 "fakedns": null,
 "inbounds": [
   {
     "listen": "127.0.0.1",
     "port": 62789,
     "protocol": "dokodemo-door",
     "settings": {
       "address": "127.0.0.1"
     },
     "sniffing": null,
     "streamSettings": null,
     "tag": "api"
   },
   {
     "listen": null,
     "port": 443,
     "protocol": "vless",
     "settings": {
       "clients": [
         {
           "email": "ouk49leh",
           "flow": "",
           "id": "62f2ccdc-7099-41df-8f51-c9e48548006c"
         }
       ],
       "decryption": "none",
       "fallbacks": []
     },
     "sniffing": {
       "destOverride": [
         "http",
         "tls",
         "quic",
         "fakedns"
       ],
       "enabled": true,
       "metadataOnly": false,
       "routeOnly": false
     },
     "streamSettings": {
       "network": "tcp",
       "realitySettings": {
         "dest": "yahoo.com:443",
         "maxClient": "",
         "maxTimediff": 0,
         "minClient": "",
         "privateKey": "SLNqewzmrlNJohNI3JIJ3OwNrC_eCMHCvD1-rrOfuV4",
         "serverNames": [
           "yahoo.com",
           "www.yahoo.com"
         ],
         "shortIds": [
           "6b8b61ab9c",
           "31a892453a7bd0",
           "9d41",
           "79799cf76283",
           "3b",
           "c7c0680601e2edf8",
           "43a73f",
           "3c564d59"
         ],
         "show": false,
         "xver": 0
       },
       "security": "reality",
       "tcpSettings": {
         "acceptProxyProtocol": false,
         "header": {
           "type": "none"
         }
       }
     },
     "tag": "inbound-443"
   }
 ],
 "log": {
   "access": "none",
   "dnsLog": false,
   "error": "./error.log",
   "loglevel": "warning"
 },
 "observatory": null,
 "outbounds": [
   {
     "protocol": "freedom",
     "settings": {
       "domainStrategy": "UseIP"
     },
     "tag": "direct"
   },
   {
     "protocol": "blackhole",
     "settings": {},
     "tag": "blocked"
   }
 ],
 "policy": {
   "levels": {
     "0": {
       "statsUserDownlink": true,
       "statsUserUplink": true
     }
   },
   "system": {
     "statsInboundDownlink": true,
     "statsInboundUplink": true,
     "statsOutboundDownlink": true,
     "statsOutboundUplink": true
   }
 },
 "reverse": null,
 "routing": {
   "domainStrategy": "AsIs",
   "rules": [
     {
       "inboundTag": [
         "api"
       ],
       "outboundTag": "api",
       "type": "field"
     },
     {
       "ip": [
         "geoip:private"
       ],
       "outboundTag": "blocked",
       "type": "field"
     },
     {
       "outboundTag": "blocked",
       "protocol": [
         "bittorrent"
       ],
       "type": "field"
     }
   ]
 },
 "stats": {},
 "transport": null
}

